# Render deploy problem "cannot find module typescript"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm having a poblem to deploy my application, it is a server built using fastify and typescript, here is my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "expense-manager-back",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Expense Manager.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "tsx watch src/server.ts",
        "build": "npm install && npx tsup src --out-dir build",
        "start": "node build/server.js",
        "test": "vitest run",
        "test:watch": "vitest"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rocketseat/eslint-config": "2.1.0",
        "@types/bcryptjs": "2.4.6",
        "@types/node": "20.9.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.10.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.10.0",
        "eslint": "8.53.0",
        "prisma": "5.5.2",
        "tsup": "7.2.0",
        "tsx": "4.0.0",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "4.2.1",
        "vitest": "0.34.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "typescript": "5.2.2",
        "@fastify/cors": "8.0.0",
        "@fastify/jwt": "7.2.3",
        "@prisma/client": "5.5.2",
        "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
        "dotenv": "16.3.1",
        "fastify": "4.24.3",
        "zod": "3.22.4"
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of chat gpt advices but none of them helped me, i tried using typescript as devDependencies but had the same issue, I keep receiving the same error

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript' Nov 27 02:46:49 AM  Require Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10) Nov 27 02:46:49 AM      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) Nov 27 02:46:49 AM      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) Nov 27 02:46:49 AM      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) Nov 27 02:46:49 AM  ==> Build failed

Comment: are you tried installing typescript globally?

Comment: I've already tried it, by puting "npm install -g typescript" in the build comand on Render, but I keep getting "Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the dependencies in the "devDependencies", render wasn't installing the 'tsup' dependecie so thats why it wans't deploying